# VB6 - How to do a multi level sort with MSFlexGrid?

Tags: sorting, gridview, vb6, msflexgrid

I currently have a VB6 program that essential reads data from an excel worksheet and spits it out into a MSFlexGrid.

Below is the excel sheet data that is read in. Data is filled into the occurence column for the **left half** of the table.

[[image]

<sub>(source: [dipzo.com](http://www.dipzo.com/initial.PNG))</sub>](http://www.dipzo.com/initial.PNG)

The VB6 Application then read this data into a multi dimensional array which is then fed into a MSFlexGrid object.
Here is the code to do that:

```
Private Sub GridSort(temp() As String)
fgData.Rows = UBound(temp)
x = 0
 Do While x < fgData.Rows
    fgData.Row = x
    fgData.Col = 0
    fgData.Text = temp(x, 0)
    fgData.Col = 1
    fgData.Text = temp(x, 1)
    x = x + 1
  Loop
  fgData.ColSel = 1
  fgData.Sort = flexSortGenericDescending
  x = 0
  Do While x < fgData.Rows
    fgData.Row = x
    fgData.Col = 0
    temp(x, 0) = fgData.Text
    fgData.Col = 1
    temp(x, 1) = fgData.Text
    x = x + 1
  Loop

End Sub
```

Now this works to a degree. It sorts the Data by occurences and outputs as so:

[[image]

<sub>(source: [dipzo.com](http://www.dipzo.com/end.PNG))</sub>](http://www.dipzo.com/end.PNG)

However, you can see that it messed up the order of the first column. I want the data to be sorted by occurences first, but for data with the same amount of occurences, I want them sorted by operation. Does anybody know a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The MSFlexGrid is sorting data in multiple columns by sorting the columns from left to right and always in the same order (descending/ascending). So you could swap the columns "occurence" and "operation" to achieve your goal.

Elsewhise, I found [here](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/t35110.html) a nice collection of MSFlexGrid functions and there's also one entry for multi-column sorting. Look for the entry "Sorting multiple columns". Didn't test it, but you could give it a try.